# Report viewer problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting, reportviewer

I'm using Report viewer to generate the report.following is the code i'm using

```
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\Saga\Desktop\projectvn\VehicleReport.rdlc";

    ReportParameter Param1 = new ReportParameter("@BrandName", "Toyota");
      ReportParameter[] p1 = { Param1 };
     ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p1);
```

It gives the following Exception

```
An error occurred during local report processing
```

Can any one plz help?

Comment: Post the InnerException and the stack trace.

Comment: Inner Exception- {"An attempt was made to set a report parameter '@BrandName' that is not defined in this report."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've added the parameter in the report (Menu Report > Report Parameters) and if you have done that already, make sure that is not marked as internal otherwise the parameter is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Sure looks to me like the parameter '@BrandName' is specified incorrectly... can you double-check its name in the actual report file? Perhaps it has different capitalization (e.g. "@Brandname") or spacing ("@Brand_Name") or no at-sign ("BrandName").,,

Answer (score 0):

Definatly looks to be the report side.  Make sure you have a paramter called @BrandName and that what ever the control is, make sure its using it something like:

```
=Parameters!@BrandName.Value
```

This is just standard there are other methods for different things like fields etc